# How to represent a property value in excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

My code works fine with generating an excel file, thanks to this community here. 
But I still have a problem:

I have a ListBox from which I export a data to an excel file.
When I run it and the file will be created, I open it and in the rows I see
*"SheduleMenager.Employees"*

Employees is the class in my project in which i have two properties:
`string Name`  and  `bool Experience`

Here is a button to create and fill up the excel file :

```
private void Generateexcelfile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < MonBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, 1] = MonBox.Items[i].ToString();
    }
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("FILEPATH", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
    xlApp.Quit();
}
```

I would be really happy if you can help me to represent a VALUE of `Employees.Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that `MonBox` contains list of employees, in `Items` collection.
If that is so, change your line

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, 1] = MonBox.Items[i].ToString();
```

into

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, 1] = (MonBox.Items[i] as SheduleMenager.Employees).Name;
```

Comment: hey i've tried this one with MonBox.Items[i].Name but visual return me an error like this : 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: As I said, I am guessing. Try casting `MonBox.Items[i]` into appropriate type. I have edited my answer

Comment: @R.Vandal glad i could help. Mark this response as an answer as a way to say thanks ;)